# Facebook Like Button creating divs with CSS styles of -2000px, creating white boxes on site

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, facebook-like

I'm using the standard HTML5 FB Like plugin, and all seemed to be well - until I viewed a page on my site that is lengthy, and I noticed two boxes in the middle of my content, well away from the Facebook Like button. I've had the same issue with the XFBML version.

By looking at the code of the button that is generated, I  can see that a `div` is created inside of `div id="fb-root">` with its styles set to `position: absolute; top: -2000px;`.

If you go to [connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js), you can see that this is created and set on line 26, col 2282. It says: `ga.style.position='absolute';ga.style.top='-2000px';`

**On pages less then this height, you don't see the boxes. But on pages longer then this, the boxes appear. Why? How can I get rid of these? What am I doing wrong?**

The button code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=<my app id>";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="<my page>" data-send="true" data-width="200" data-show-faces="true" 
             data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-font=\"arial\"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will happen if you have placed the `fb-root` element inside an element with an absolute or relative position, as the -2000px would otherwise be relative to the body.

If you move the `fb-root` element directly into the body then this will no longer happen.

Comment: I suppose that's why they tell you to put it at the beginning of the body tag...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
ga.style.backgroundColor='transparent';
```

or:

```
ga.style.visibility='hidden';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't edit the connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js and I'm not really looking for a hack solution; obviously I'm one of the few this is an issue for, so I must be doing something wrong

Comment: You should be able to detect this element and manipulate the style within your own script. The implementation seems like a hack so you may not have any real choice other than to jump on board.

Comment: What do you mean the implementation seems like a hack? This is the exact code that the Facebook Developers Like button generator produces. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: anything with a style of -2000px is a hack, even if it's authored by a Facebook dev.